# creating custom panes for field data in drupal 7

Tags: entities

I need to port a panel feature from drupal 6 to drupal 7. I am able to get all the panel fields that come from views and blocks. Only thing i am not able to get is the fields that are coming from the content types.

Editing the panel shows "This pane's content type is either missing or has been deleted. This pane will not render." in the pane. The code generating this pane is

```
$pane->css = array();
  $pane->extras = array();
  $pane->position = 2;
  $display->content['new-4'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['top'][2] = 'new-4';
  $pane = new stdClass;
  $pane->pid = 'new-5';
  $pane->panel = 'top_left';
  $pane->type = 'content_field';
  $pane->subtype = '<field name>';
  $pane->shown = TRUE;
  $pane->access = array();
  $pane->configuration = array(
    'label' => 'inline',
    'formatter' => 'default',
    'context' => 'argument_nid_1',
    'override_title' => 0,
    'override_title_text' => '',
  );
```

The content_field type requires a plugin content_field.inc which was present in cck module in drupal6 as 'cck/includes/panels/content_types/content_field.inc'. How do i port this thing in drupal 7. There should be something equivalent to content_field.inc in drupal7 
also.

Can someone lemme know how to get over this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got his one. We need to replace content_fields with entity_+fields in drupal 7 as the content types are entity type in drupal 7 now.

Thanks